# Excel IF function with 3 conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have three conditions if I want to join in one and I can not join them without an error. The sentence is as follows:
1. `=SI(F22<7,BUSCARV(F22,B19:C24,2,FALSO),"Operación no definida")`
2. `=SI(F22=4,G19<>0,"No se puede realizar la operación")`
3. `=SI(F22=4,G19<>0,"No se puede realizar la operación")`

Comment: 2 and 3 look identical, and the second argument shouldn't be a comparison.

Comment: You may want to look into [the `Y` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/and-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9), like so:  `=SI(Y(F22=4,G19<>0),"No se puede realizar la operación", "Algo más")`

Comment: AND() function for multiple conditions?

Comment: Isn’t there a spanish stack you could post on?

Comment: I don't see the example of how you have tried to join them.

Comment: There are a couple of hundred Excel questions on Stack Overflow en español - https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel - where they might be more familiar with the Spanish function names

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed an AND in your second and third conditions:

```
=SI(AND(F22=4,G19<>0),"No se puede realizar la operación", "NO ELSE CONDITION")
```

or maybe OR()?